# Cannot resolve symbol ILocationManager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am having the following error in Android Studio.

[image]

Unable to resolve symbol ILocationManager and others in LocationManager.java which is a sdk file. I am using LocationManager to find the latitude and longitude in my android library.

This is my gradle file for library

```
{apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I tried removing the exclude group in build gradle file  and building it but it didnt work.

Note: This is not for only one file but many other files of the sdk (so something wrong with the sdk?)

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Comment: @Honey'L, I dont think it causes an issue with your coding. So continue with it.